# Run Android (Web) App on Windows PC?

Tags: gmail

Gmail has a [new beautiful design](https://www.theverge.com/2019/2/20/18233097/gmail-redesign-android-available-material-design-google-play-store) since January. However, it looks like the rollout takes some time since it didn't arrive yet for the regular web version.

So my question/idea was: can I run the (Android) tablet version somehow on a Windows PC? In the end, it is most probably a web app anyway running in the background? This would allow me to be able to use the new design already without having to buy a tablet...

PS: It is so unfair (in my opinion) that mobile devices nowadays are preferred over PCs for most applications. Even though the most productive use of certain apps is still with a PC...but that's another story for another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to run the Android version of Gmail on desktop PC. All you need is to download an Android emulator like:

- Nox - **https://www.bignox.com/**
- Bluestacks - **https://www.bluestacks.com/**
- Droid4x - **https://droid4x.en.uptodown.com/windows**
- Genymotion - **https://www.genymotion.com/#!/**
- KoPlayer - **http://www.koplayer.com/**
- and many more...

Comment: Thanks! Is it safe to use with a Google account? Does the emulator get access to the login data?

Comment: yes, it's safe. protocols prevent access to emulators outside your network